# Using atoi and error :unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have been working on this code for my class and I am just not sure what the errors mean or how to fix them. Also, I am not sure what the next step is or how I can finish the program. I have only been using C++ for a month and I am not very familiar with any of it. Thank you in advance!

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl parseDate(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?parseDate@@YAHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

**My assignment is:**
A parking garage charges a $2.00 minimum fee to park for up to three hours. The garage charges an additional $0.50 per hour for each hour or part thereof in excess of three hours. The maximum charge for any given 24-hour period is $10.00. People who park their cars for longer than 24 hours will pay $8.00 per day.
Write a program that calculates and prints the parking charges. The inputs to your program are the date and time when a car enters the parking garage, and the date and time when the same car leaves the parking garage. Both inputs are in the format of: YY/MM/DD hh:mm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string startDateString;
string endDateString;
string dateStr;
int parseDate( string dateStr );

int main ()

{

string enter_date;
string enter_time;
string exit_date;
string exit_time;
cout << "Please enter the date and time the car is entering "<< endl
    << "the parking garage in the following format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm"<< endl;
getline (cin,dateStr);//cin >> enter_date >> enter_time;

cout<< "Please enter the date and time the car is exiting "<< endl
    << "the parking garage in the following format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm"<< endl;
getline (cin,dateStr);//cin >> exit_date >> exit_time;


{
    // Format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm
    int year  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 0, 2 ).c_str() );
    int month = atoi( dateStr.substr( 3, 2 ).c_str() );
    int day   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 6, 2 ).c_str() );
    int hour  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 9, 2 ).c_str() );
    int min   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 12, 2 ).c_str() );

    // Now calculate no. of mins and return this
    int totalMins = 0;
    totalMins += ( year * 365 * 24 * 60 ); 
    totalMins += ( month * 30 * 24 * 60 ); 
    totalMins += ( day * 24 * 60 );        
    totalMins += ( hour * 60 );
    totalMins += ( min );

    return totalMins;
}
int startTime = parseDate( startDateString );
int endTime   = parseDate( endDateString );
int elapsedTime = endTime - startTime; // elapsedTime is no. of minutes parked

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The format of your code is wrong, you haven't defined the parseDate function

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you never defined `parseDate()` separately, but instead mooshed it inside your `main()`.  I think you need to take out:

```
{
    // Format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm
    int year  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 0, 2 ).c_str() );
    int month = atoi( dateStr.substr( 3, 2 ).c_str() );
    int day   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 6, 2 ).c_str() );
    int hour  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 9, 2 ).c_str() );
    int min   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 12, 2 ).c_str() );

    // Now calculate no. of mins and return this
    int totalMins = 0;
    totalMins += ( year * 365 * 24 * 60 ); 
    totalMins += ( month * 30 * 24 * 60 ); 
    totalMins += ( day * 24 * 60 );        
    totalMins += ( hour * 60 );
    totalMins += ( min );

    return totalMins;
}
```

And put it in a separate function at the end of your code:

```
int parseDate (string dateStr) 
{
    // Format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm
    int year  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 0, 2 ).c_str() );
    int month = atoi( dateStr.substr( 3, 2 ).c_str() );
    int day   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 6, 2 ).c_str() );
    int hour  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 9, 2 ).c_str() );
    int min   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 12, 2 ).c_str() );

    // Now calculate no. of mins and return this
    int totalMins = 0;
    totalMins += ( year * 365 * 24 * 60 ); 
    totalMins += ( month * 30 * 24 * 60 ); 
    totalMins += ( day * 24 * 60 );        
    totalMins += ( hour * 60 );
    totalMins += ( min );

    return totalMins;
}
```

Comment: so I should not put it in the main function? It is also saying that it terminated in an unusual way and to contact the support team after moving it outside the main function

Comment: @user - In this case, **you** are the support team! Remember who delivered the program. :-) "Terminated in an unusual way" usually means that the code is throwing an exception. Like when trying to parse `startDateString` and `endDateString` when the input really is in `dateStr`.